# how to implement "move to" function as seen in Google Drive using Google Drive java SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a Java server side application that needs to move files from the "Shared to me" folder to a specific folder "folder1" every time someone shares a file to me. This function exists in Drive UI using the "move to" menu entry, but when I tried to add the "folder1" id to the parents of the file shared to me using the files.update or files.patch API I got 404 error, while files.get with the same file id does get the file metadata back without any problem. When I examined what api was called by Google Drive when I invoked the "move to" menu entry I saw a post to https://drive.google.com/ar. My question is, what is the right way to implement the "move to" functionality? Is there an API exposed for https://drive.google.com/ar?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the 404 error by giving my java code write permission to the file. I am still curious to know if there is any API counterpart for https://drive.google.com/ar?